# Mock non-standalone dependencies in standalone components for unit tests

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test, angular-standalone-components

I have a standalone component with some non-standalone dependencies. These dependencies were added with related modules to the imports array. How can I mock dependencies of non-standalone components for Unit tests. I have all needed stub components, but can't figure out how to add these dependencies, because I can include only modules.
Here is the component decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: 'app-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app-test.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [LoaderModule, SharedModule],
})
```

In LoaderModule, SharedModule i have some components that i want to mock. Do I need to create some module with all needed stub dependencies and include it in the standalone imports array?

Comment: You should give ng-mocks a try. It has some really nice auto-mock features especially for components. Services still must be manually provided by hand or explicitly using MockProvider method.

see: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/

Comment: Do you use a TestBed for tests? Could you please provide an example of your test configuration?